# Hard String Tension on a short neck (Change Gauge?)

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, strings, string-gauge

I have an Ibanez 1570 (24 Frets) and love the tension and an EVH Wolfgang Special.

I always use Gauge: 9 to 42

The wolfgang special has a shorter neck but the tension is really hard. Why?

I've every been thinking on trying 08's on my Wolfgang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you mean the SCALE of the Special's neck is shorter, as in the length from nut to bridge. If this is so, the strings like for like, should actually be looser than those on the Ibanez, for the same tuning.It sounds like the ACTION is too high on the Special, making the strings harder to press as they have further to go to get to the fretboard.The reasons are either the neck needs tweaking, or the saddles need lowering, or probably both. These need to be sorted before you try .008s. By all means use .008s, but expect a loss in tone and sustain, as they are 11% thinner !

The adjustments have been discussed elsewhere on this site, but if you are not sure how to do it, leave it to an expert.

Comment: I would avoid the neck adjustment, but the action and intonation adjustments on many electric guitars is a five minute job with an allen wrench and a screwdriver and runs nearly no risk of damage to the instrument. The worst case is paying finding an expert to put it back if he fails. He should take a chance. I believe in him!